# Elusive common geometric parameter / property in spherical triangles set

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

A constant length $(=a)$ segment of a variable great circle has its extremities $(P,Q)$ moving along fixed Longitudes $(L1,L2)$ passing through North pole $N.$

Please help to identify the geometric parameter with invariant property $\dfrac{\sin a}{\sin A}$ associated with the set of spherical triangles $ NPQ.$

[image: Elusive common Invariant]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Does the sin rules for spherical triangles may help? $\frac{\sin a}{\sin A}=\frac{\sin b}{\sin B}=\frac{\sin c}{\sin C}$

Comment: What geometric object of the spherical triangle set possesses the above property? For flat trigonometry corresponding object is the *circum-diameter*